# Trainer game / drills to master command line?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, games

Looking for recommendations, for some simple trainer style games to become better with the command line.

It could be something similar to https://www.learnshell.org/, or even simpler. At the most basic level, I would be happy to just get a prompt, and feedback, doesn't have to be Ultima Ascension. :)

Comment: Welcome! This question is not specifically about Ubuntu, so likely off topic on AskUbuntu. There's a dedicated StackExchange site for software recommendations, which may be a better home to this question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Asked the same question here, as per @valiano's suggestion https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53871/educational-games-to-master-unix-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# stop on error
set -o errexit

# don't allow unset variables
set -o nounset

# don't overwrite any files
set -o noclobber

# prompt the user
read -p "Proceed? [N/y]: " PROCEED

# make "n" (no) the default
PROCEED=${PROCEED:-"n"}

# convert the user's response to lower case for easier interpretation
# interpret the user's response
if [ "${PROCEED,,}" = 'y' ]; then
    echo "Proceeding..."
else
    echo "Stopping"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Personally I would prefer command line interface for training command line commands, so yeah, could be something like that.